# wand.Image object to PIL Image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, wand

I currently have an image in the wand.image format. I need to convert it to PIL format so that I can continue working with it. It is and RGB image. I cant seem to find anywhere how to do it. I have tried to convert it to an np array and then read the np array into the PIL image.  Thank you for any help. Here is my code if it helps:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
from wand.image import Image as Image2

with Image2(filename=join(img_path,file)) as img:
   img.virtual_pixel = 'transparent'
   test_image = Image.fromarray(np.array(img), 'RGB')
```

Comment: That looks correct. What happened for you to say it doesn't work? The `img.virtual_pixel = 'transparent'` seems redundant, by the way. Try `print(img)` immediately after the line containing `with ...`

Comment: it doesnt create an error. When I save the image it produces something that doesnt look correct at all, due to it being lines of random colors pretty much. I was applying a fisheye distortion to the image and that line was part of the code. I left it in just in case it was doing something i didnt understand.

Comment: And what did `print(img)` produce please?

Comment: Check the shape of the `np.array(img)`. One library might be expecting `HEIGHT x WIDTH`, and another `WIDTH x HEIGHT`.

Comment: I ended up using data_image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(img.make_blob("png"))).convert('RGB'). I found it after some more searching.

Comment: Might be worth checking versions. Code provided works fine with Wand-0.6.2

Comment: @emcconville strange, i had some other stuff being done to the image later on, but I didnt have to change anything but that line of code to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

data_image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(img.make_blob("png"))).convert('RGB') fixes the issue for some reason